# Регулярное выражение для положительных целых четных чисел

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как найти положительные (то есть без знака "-" перед) целые (без знаков "." и "," после) числа при помощи регулярного выражения?

Мой почти рабочий вариант: `(?<![-.,])((\d*[24680])+(?![.,]))+`.

Однако в таком случае в числах, например, 445 и 167 будут совпадения "44" и "16": http://prntscr.com/lnxvg3

Comment: Может, `(?<![-\d]|\d[.,])\d*[24680](?![.,]?\d)`? См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/2ix2UA/1).

Comment: Немного поправила: `(?<![-.,])((\d*[24680])+(?![.,])(?!\d))` и отлично работает. Спасибо!

Comment: А последний вариант?  https://regex101.com/r/2ix2UA/1 ? Зачем вам столько лишних групп?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , да, действительно. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Гм, с учётом того, что обрабатываются и точка, и запятая, возможны числа в разных культурах. Но есть культуры, в которых отрицательные числа записываются без знака минус, но в скобках: `-5` == `(5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Я предлагаю

```
(?<![-\d])(?<!\d[.,])\d*[24680](?![.,]?\d)
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/2ix2UA/2)

**Подробности**

- `(?<![-\d])` - перед текущей позицией не должно быть цифры или минуса
- `(?<!\d[.,])` - перед текущей позицией не должно быть цифры и точки либо запятой
- `\d*` - 0 и более любых цифр
- `[24680]` - одна из указанных цифр
- `(?![.,]?\d)` -  после текущей позиции не должно быть точки либо запятой (опционально) и потом цифры.

Если необходимо избавиться от совпадений, состоящих из одних нулей, можно добавить исключающий блок предварительной проверки вперёд ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/2ix2UA/6)):

```
(?<![-\d])(?<!\d[.,])(?!0+(?!\d))\d*[24680](?![.,]?\d)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Или воспользоваться "сверхжадными" квантификаторами (если они доступны) (заодно это решение отсекает начальные нули):

```
(?<![-\d])(?<!\d[.,])0*+(\d*[24680])(?![.,]?\d)
                     ^^^^--Группа1-^
```

См. [ещё одно демо](https://regex101.com/r/2ix2UA/4)

Comment: В такое выражение попадает еще и просто 0: https://regex101.com/r/EYMApb/1 , подскажите, как его исключить, но при этом не исключить числа типа 60, 100, 250 и т.д. ?

Comment: @yellowfish Это требование можно реализовать по-разному в зависимости от конкретных требований к шаблону и библиотеки регулярных выражений. Например, для тех, что поддерживают "сверхжадные" квантификаторы, подойдёт `(?<![-\d])(?<!\d[.,])0*+(\d*[24680])(?![.,]?\d)` (нужное значение будет в группе №1, см. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/2ix2UA/4)).